# where can I find free chess books?

Tags: learning, books, websites, online, recommendations

I need a website where I can find free chess ebooks? I would like to see a list of free books to download or read online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find some resources:

- [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=chess) is a library with over 70,000 free e-books.
- [infobooks](https://www.infobooks.org/free-pdf-books/sports/chess/) has 20 free chess books.
- You can find four free chess books on this website : [1000exercices](https://www.1000exercices.info/books/).
- You can find many free chess books in [pdfdrive](https://www.pdfdrive.com/chess-books.html) and [epdf](https://epdf.tips/search/chess).
- In this [blog](https://bishopsbounty.blogspot.com/2009/01/free-online-chess-books.html) you can see a list of free books in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/).
- Finally, the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/books?query=chess)
  is a non-profit library of millions of free books.

Comment: also i have found a certain torrent file which had 1500+ chess books

Answer (score 2):

[ChessUtilities Reader](https://reader.chessutilities.com/) has some 1000+ eBooks for free and [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=chess) is also not bad for chess books.